# Is there simple way to convert the values into int format using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logistic-regression

[image]

There are about 40 different values in the col "Weather_Condition", in .csv. Is there a simple way to map them to integer values for later use in the col as y variable in Logistic Regression?

Comment: Do you want to count occurrences of each weather condition and store them as an integer?

Comment: You will need an OCR package to read that image.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(<filename>)
df['Weather_Condition'] = pd.Categorical(df['Weather_Condition'])
y = df['Weather_Condition'].codes
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

How about using Label Encoder ?

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
data = ['Light Rain', 'Overcast', 'Cloudy', 'Snow']
lencoder = LabelEncoder()
encoded = lencoder.fit_transform(data)
print(encoded)
```

Inverse transform would look like below;

```
inverted = lencoder.inverse_transform([0])
print(inverted)
```

Hope it was helpful.

PS:Also if you are interested take a look at one-hot-encoder;